# Where can I learn about Serach bat Asher?

Tags: women, jacob

Looking for any books on the topic that go into all the aspects to her. Thanks.

Comment: This is am article which lists sources in footnotes... https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5329601/jewish/8-Fascinating-Facts-About-Serach-Daughter-of-Asher.htm

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/932615/rabbi-mordechai-djavaheri/elul-in-esfahan-the-shrine-of-serach-bat-asher/

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider Rabbi Yishai Chasida's incredible *[Ishei HaTanach](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899060255.html)* - it features a page (p.526) on her singling out several midrashim and maamarei chazal.